# Extract plaintext within Div that includes other dom elements but not within any tags

Tags: php, html, dom, scrape

I'm trying to extract some plain text that isn't wrapped in any tags using PHP. Best way to explain is to show;

```
<div>
    <span>Hello</span>
        THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT
    <span>this is some other text</span>
    <div><span>pow</span></div>
</div>
```

What I'm just about to try out is to loop through and remove all dom elements within the div and that should leave the text. But I'm hoping there's a more elegant method :)

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, you want to get the text for the element, but excluding the text for child elements.

Using JavaScript, there is a solution for that here:

http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201007/Blog/Jquery-Get-Text-While-Excluding-Children/

And in summary, you would do this...

```
$("#mydiv").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

In PHP (using phpquery) this would be...

```
$phpqueryObj = phpQuery::newDocument(DOMinnerHTML($INNERHTMLOFYOURDOMELEMENT));
$text = $phpqueryObj->clone()->children()->remove()->end()->text();
```

Without jQuery / JavaScript you would have to perform a similar process manually, i.e. remove the child elements form a cloned version of the element and then get the inner text.

Comment: This works in phpquery (I'm not using javascript). God knows how :D but it does! thanks Sohnee

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would probably be to use XPath given the context node.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
//find all div nodes
foreach ($xpath->query('//div') as $div) {
   //get any immediate child text nodes
   foreach ($xpath->query('text()', $div) as $text) {
      echo "$text->nodeValue\n";
   }
}
```

Do note that the first query will return *all* divs, so you have to make it more specific for the divs you want.

I tested the code above on your example and it works.

Comment: This method also works, however due to its complexity n2 (loop inside a loop) this could potentially be slower that the other version

Comment: You need to go back to school.  This is O(log n), O(n) in worst case (I don't know the inner workings of DOMDocument).  Two loops does not O(n^2) make. I also don't know the inner workings of $(), .clone(), .children(), .remove(), .end(), .text() ... how do you know that none of these are O(n^2) themselves?

Comment: Indeed, the other could well be more complex. Sorry for my miscalculation (was thinking of a for loop). Note though that I rated your comment up anyway :)

Comment: You can save yourself the inner loop by using `//div/text()` as the xpath expression.

Comment: Nice one Yoshi, xpath is a dark art I swear